# Git checkout earlier commit, do changes, make it new master

Tags: git

I have a project. Encountered a bug. Went to the previous commit (without a bug). Made some changes. Now want it to be the new master discarding the old one with the bug.

I put it this way.
If I haven't made any changes in the commit I went to, would just hard reset to it from master and force push. That way I would have "discarded" the bugged version, and ruled with the new one on origin master.
But I made changes. I want the commit I went to to be the new master, but with the changes, I have made.

I put it another way because I couldn't find any solution without branching for this simple and straight forward thing to do.

I have the following structure:

- A -- master origin (a bug I don't want)
- B
- C -- head with changes already made (i am currently here, no bug)
- D

How do I make it to be like this?

- C -- master origin head and whatnot with the changes I have made while being in a detached state
- A -- removed as I don't care, or kept as I don't care
- B -- removed because I don't care, or kept as I don't care
- D

Simply shift my C commit up. Why would I need branches and then conflict resolvings?

Comment: The main idea of git is to work with other people. You will disrupt their workflow if you force-push to master. This goes for every branch that you are not working on exclusively on your own. As such, the proper way would be to push a commit that fixes your bug and go on with your day. A slightly messy commit history is almost always better than rewriting history.

Comment: I don't understand your structure. Are those branches or commits or what? If commits, why is your HEAD behind D? Is it on another branch? You'll never ever be able to "shift up C", at most you can destroy C and create a new commit, with the same content, but a different name and parents, typically C'. If you are working on a separate branch, no need to worry: get back on master, git cherry-pick the commits you want then create a new commit with that content directly on master. If you can do so and your company has no standards in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new commit based on `A` and the new commit has the same tree with `C`. If 2 commits have the same tree object, their checked-out folders and files are exactly the same.

```
git checkout master # master is at A
git merge $(git commit-tree -p HEAD -m foo C^{tree}) # replace C with the actual SHA1
git commit --amend # edit "foo" with a detailed description
```

`git commit-tree -p HEAD -m foo C^{tree}` creates a commit and returns its SHA1. Its parent is `HEAD`, `A` in this case. Its commit message log is `foo`, which you can modify with `git commit --amend` later. Its tree is `C`'s tree.

Comment: why not just `git merge C`?

Comment: `C` and `A` are diveged. Merging `C` to `A` may cause conflicts. And in this case, it can't revert the changes introduced by `B` and `A` without extra efforts.